# login template accepting every input

Tags: jquery, templates, authentication

I recently used a login template from W3layouts. 
You can see it here: http://www.schildercursusarnhem.nl/login.html 
The problem is that any given person can log in with any made up username and/or password. 
I can't figger out where I need to change or set the change so that access is only granted to registered users.

Sorry, for some reason I can't insert the codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP and SQL to check if user is registered and then allow to enter you page or redirect to login page again. Have you tried that ? can you use php/sql ?

edit:

You will need to edit this file:
    http://www.schildercursusarnhem.nl/js/login.js

and change:

```
if ( username == "student" && password == "iskander"){
        alert ("Login successfully");
        window.location = "success.html"; //redirecting to other page
        return false;
    }
```

your username is:student and your password is: iskander

But this is not the way you should verify login details. This is visible to everyone and it's easy to get an access to your page. You should go with PHP and SQL solution.

Comment: NO experience with php or sql. My guess is that it would complicate things here since the whole login template was made ready to use. based on html, css and js.
My question is where I have to change the settings for accepting usernames etc.

Comment: Thanks Fernando, 
After some more research I managed to solved the problem.

Comment: did my answer helped you ? feel free to accept it :)

Comment: Hi Fernando, still working on this. The fact is that the material which is in the secure section of the site isn't so much very private as it is only excessible for students. 
But, I'm trying to figger out how to create a saver way with your suggestion. 
I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting this form to naslag.html and not checking anything on any fields.
You can either validate username/password in naslag.html page or call any javascript function before submitting this login.html page.

Comment: thank you p2p.
Could you tell me where I activate the validation? shoudl this be done in the js file or css file?

Comment: Password validation should always happen on the server.

Comment: @Arion you should validate password server side and you can trigger call to server from login.html itself. What you have used as server side?